# Unable to login to a user(oracle) "error: resource temporary unavailable"

Tags: linux, limit

When I try to login to `oracle` via `ssh` or `su - oracle` it shows following error

```
**error:resource temporary unavailable**
```

CPU Memory & IOps utilization is normal

Comment: Welcome to the site. Though you have solved the problem yourself, your question can be made more helpful to others if you edit it to include information on your exact OS flavour and version, and the oracle installation you are using.

Answer (score -1):

I've done following diagnostics:

[image: process count on oracle user]

[image]

I found that process count for `oracle` user is much higher than `nproc` soft limit for the `oracle` user.

I change the `nproc` soft limit to 8192 in in `90-nproc.conf`. This change resolved the issue.

Comment: Congratulations on solving the issue yourself. However, if at all possible please avoid attaching screenshots of sonsole output, copy-and-paste it with appropriate code formatting instead. This usually makes it easier for users to reproduce solutions you provide.

Comment: Please post text as text. It makes it easier (possible) for blind people to read.